# "Favorites" Shows New Entry - But I didn't add any

Tags: support, bookmarks

I went to my profile and noticed this today:

> [image: Favorites]

I set the filter to "newest" and the first question in the list was indeed a question I remember *favorite-ing*, but definitely not today. I do check my profile everyday to go through any unseen comments/rep changes so it's not a case of *the listing being there for a while; just that I didn't visit the profile in a long time*

So I'm curious as to what made it to be flagged as a new entry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The indicator doesn't mean you have made a question a favorite.

It indicates that a question that you have made favorite has had changes (edits, new answers).

Comment: So any way to know which question was it? I'm assuming using the "newest" filter is of no use since that question didn't have any edits/new answers to it

Nevermind..found other filters too (activity)

Comment: @asprin - when you go to that tab, the top ones...